# Getting a weird error hitting Google Apps Script from Node REST clients

Tags: json, node.js, google-apps-script, restler

I am setting up a simple Google App Script to get some data from a spreadsheet to an external app. When I open the url from my browser or curl I get the proper JSON response.

See for yourself, here is the url:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwUqrOsqQk4rk0lY97Wl4bRsHVk6_CMVPz3hGHeyc3H2ZCahCIY/exec

You should get a JSON response. I would like to have a node app make a request to that URL and parse the JSON response. I am attempting with two different clients, restler and request, and with both I get this error:

```
Error: 140735264762208:error:0607907F:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA:expecting an rsa
key:../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/evp/p_lib.c:288
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: I've been seeing the same thing for a few days, but not happening consistently depending where in the world you are.  I suspect one of their server is misconfigured, and if your request hits that one, then you are stuck.  It eventually works again if I wait long enough, then breaks again.  It has not bothered me enough yet to file a bug on their tracker.

Comment: Looks like you're right, I am home from work and having no issues. Guess I was consistently hitting a problem server earlier.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is a known Node.js issue that there is already a fix in progress for - https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/4827